# MVVM - Hide Datagrid column based on column name with autogeneratecolumns = True

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datagrid

I have a `DataGrid` that's bound to `Datatable`, and I want to uniquely identify rows in the `DataTable` using the `ID`, but I don't want it to be shown in the `DataGrid`

What I reached so far by searching and excluding:

1. Data columns are not predefined, so, I have to use `AutoGenerateColumns=True`, hence, I can't define the columns manually and set the `Visibility` property to `False`.
2. I can't use `List` or `ObservableCollection` to define private `ID` member, because the data are dynamic.
3. I am following `MVVM` so, I can't use `AutoGeneratingColumns` event handler directly and can't expose the `View` to the `ViewModel`.

The closest I get to an answer is using `DataTrigger` to set `Visibility` to `False` using `CellStyle`, but it just hid the cells, not the entire column, and I also tried it for `DataGridColumnHeader` and it didn't work:

code:

```
        <Style x:Key="ColumnStyle" TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=Value}" Value="id">
                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"></Setter>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

How to do it while maintaining the previous conditions?
Thanks in advance

### EDIT:

I fixed the code for `DataGridColumnHeader` using `Path=Column.Header` which doesn't make sense to me but it's irrelevant; Still, there and empty column standing there, with no idea how to remove it.

Comment: After my first guess was wrong, a few questions: Why and how do you not know what will be exposed in that DataGrid? Where does the data come from? What does it represent? What class are you using to store it (ExpandoObject, Dictionary, Dynamic, other)?

Comment: I mean I should'ne use the DataGrid object, not the data within it. Sorry if I expressed it wrong...

I am using DataTable

Comment: No, I mean this part "Data columns are not predefined". It is really confusing that you do not know wich Properties each Collection Item will have. Why are you not just mapping them to a set of proper ViewModel classes and taraget templates on those?

Comment: Data columns are defined in ViewModel per use ... but in design-time I don't know what are the columns or how many columns are there

Comment: yes. I understood that when you wrote it into the question. **Why** is it like that?

Comment: Because the data comes from database, so I don't know what the query is, also, not all row have the same columns, some have one or more column(s)

Comment: You will only have X queries you can send. So only X amounts of possible results. Make a ViewModel class for each of them. Make a template for each ViewModel class. Done. If you ever do add a column, you will have to update the appropirate ViewModels and it's Template, but that is normal in UI design.

Comment: they are not that limited, I have more than ten tables, with some or all columns per table visible per query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution by applying this style:

```
<Style x:Key="ColumnStyle" TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=Value}" Value="id">
            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"></Setter>
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

to `DataGridCell` and to `DataGridColumnHeader` and **allocating the column in the end of the table** this removed the empty column from the middle of the table.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to track the selected Item. If you want to track the "selected Element", you have to use a CollectionView.

WPF controls do not direcly bind to collections. They bind to a CollectionView. And if you do not give them one, they will create one themself from whatever collection you hand them. If you want sorting, filtering, ordering and selection tracking, CollectionView is the droid you are looking for:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.collectionview.aspx

Just take control of it's creation and expose it (rather then the raw collection).

Comment: First; collection view manipulates the rows, not the columns, if you know some way using `collectionView` please state it explicitly.

Also, I don't need to track selected item because I made checkboxes instead, and that's exactly what I need to get from the user.